# How do you reference Twitter Bootstrap DatePicker with Script Manager

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Hi I have downloaded the [twitter bootstrap style datepicker from Stefan Petre](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

However I am stuck at trying to refrence the .js file and css files in my current project.
I have already installed the twitter bootstrap and it seems to be working fine.
I copied the bootstrap-datepicker.js file to my Scripts directory, but when I try to reference it in my master page like this:

```
<form runat="server" class="form-horizontal">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap-datepicker.js" Path="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"/>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            ...
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>       
    <div class="container body-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>            
    </div>
</form>
```

it gives the following error:
The assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not contain a Web resource that has the name 'bootstrap-datepicker.js'. Make sure that the resource name is spelled correctly.

Could someone possibly steer me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Check the following answer, if it solves your problem:
[How to Setup Date Picker][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093115/how-to-set-up-datepicker-vs-2013

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the .js from the Name and that should resolve that error

Answer (score 0):

The short answer for me, eventually distilled from the various takes in [How to set up Datepicker VS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093115/how-to-set-up-datepicker-vs-2013)
was that only the Path callout is required:

```
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js" />
```