# Why doesn't Bootstrap datepicker work here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to use datepicker from http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter.

Question updated to include complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Calendar</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="navbar.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/datepicker/css/datepicker.css">
    <script src="js/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fullcalendar-2.0.2/fullcalendar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fullcalendar-2.0.2/fullcalendar.print.css">

    <script src="js/fullcalendar-2.0.2/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fullcalendar-2.0.2/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fullcalendar-2.0.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            // put your options and callbacks here
        })

    });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <!-- Static navbar -->
      <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Calendar</a>
          </div>
          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Bookings <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </div>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <script>
         $('#dp1').datepicker({
             format: "MM-DD-YYYY",
             autoclose: true
         });
      </script>
      <div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Form</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <!-- Form -->
              <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputForename" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Forename</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputForename" placeholder="">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputSurname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Surname</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSurname" placeholder="">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputBadge" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Badge</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputBadge" placeholder="">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputStartDate" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Start Date</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dp1">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Main component to show the calendar -->
      <div id="calendar"></div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Is there something wrong in what I am doing here? It seems ok based on the examples at http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter.

Comment: Check the following Link if it helps [How to Set up Date Picker][1]How to Set Up Bootstrap Date Picker


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093115/how-to-set-up-datepicker-vs-2013

Answer (score 0):

You might need to wait until the page is loaded, then initialize the date picker

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready( function($){
     $('#dp1').datepicker({
         format: "MM-DD-YYYY",
         autoclose: true
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that and still no datepicker. Would it be ok to be using the jQuery included in another file, FullCalendar like I am doing?

Comment: It shouldn't matter as long as it's jQuery. Do you have a URL I can look at?

Comment: Yes. `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'fn' of undefined or null reference 
bootstrap-datepicker.js, line 335 character 2
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker' 
calendar, line 85 character 10
`. Does that make any sense to you?

Comment: Not overly, being able to see the page though would help though